# How do I run an argument from a program in the windows command-line?

Tags: windows, command-line

I want to run arguments from this site:

http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/documentation/command-line

So I just made a task for BleachBit on windows which works. It contains one action to start the program "D:\Win Programs\BleachBit\bleachbit_console.exe" and in the Add Arguments(optional) part I put --clean --preset.... How do I do that from the commandline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add your arguments after the executable:

```
C:\>"D:\Win Programs\BleachBit\bleachbit_console.exe" --clean --preset....
```

Comment: Is there a different way to run it in PowerShell while executing those arguments? start bleachbit_console.exe works but I don't know how to get it to run with those arguments

Comment: Should be the same in Power Shell, you don't need `start`.

Comment: it doesn't work on PowerShell but it does using the command prompt.. thanks anyways